# How to get the css selector of only a part of the element

Tags: testing, automation, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I want to click only the first part of a element which has both a hyperlink(containing a checkbox)  and non hyperlink part.In other word I want to check the checkbox.But I cannot separate only the checkbox part of the element.The selector when clicked always clicks the hyperlink part and takes me to a different page. I want to click only the part of the element which contains text `I agree to the`.I am using css selector like `'.Grid>div:nth-child(9)>button:nth-child(1)'` which chooses the entire selector or if I give `[class="terms-conditions-input"]>label>:nth-child(1)` it gives me the hyperlink part only.But I just want the css selector for the 1st part without the hyperlink. The HTML for the element is given below:

```
<div class="qa-field qa-checkbox option option-form-control terms-conditions js-question-terms-conditions">
<div class="terms-conditions-input">
<input id="question-terms-conditions" class="pull-left parsley-validated" type="checkbox" data-validate-error-message="Please agree to the Terms & Conditions to continue" data-validate-mincheck="1" data-validate-required="true" name="terms-conditions"/>
<label class="pull-left" for="question-terms-conditions">
 I agree to the 
<a title="Terms & Conditions" target="_blank" href="http://answers.walmart.com/answers/1336/content/termsandconditions.htm"> Terms & Conditions </a>
</label>
```

Is there any way to create a css selector for only  the `I agree to the` part of the element.

Comment: Wrap that text within a span and then try it.

Comment: your given html is incomplete. You can do one thing keep your label tag outside the terms-conditions-input div tag

Comment: please put complete code

Comment: @nightmag, As @Sujata Chanda suggested, wrap your `I agree to the` in a `span` / `div`, add specific class to it and access it using that combination of selectors. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/cv8vqbtz/)

Comment: Why dont you directly click on the checkbox (or change its checked property) rather than clicking on text. For eg. [class="terms-conditions-input"]>input

Answer (score 0):

As `@Sujata Chanda` suggested, wrap your `I agree to the` statement in a separate `span` or `div`, add required `id` or `class` to it and access it using that combination of selectors. like:

**HTML:**

```
<label class="pull-left" for="question-terms-conditions">
    <span class="part1">I agree to the</span>
    <a title="Terms & Conditions" target="_blank"
        href="http://answers.walmart.com/answers/1336/content/termsandconditions.htm"> 
        Terms & Conditions
    </a>
</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.terms-conditions-input label .part1 {
  color: red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/cv8vqbtz/)

Also, be more specific in writing CSS selectors using prominent id(s) or class(es), rather than using `.Grid>div:nth-child(9)>button:nth-child(1)` or `[class="terms-conditions-input"]>label>:nth-child(1)`.